# How to animate list element position change

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a ul with li that are added with Javascript, these items can be deleted and if there were items below it they're moved up, is there a way to animate this position change? I've tried applying a

```
transition: top 0.2s linear;
```

On the list item but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The removal of elements from the DOM cannot be animated as such. You would have to animate the size down or fade them out perhaps. It's not as simple as animating position.

In Jquery you could use `.slideUp` to animate the hiding and then `.remove` to extract them from the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp("normal", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}
li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
```